# Background image centered and 100% in all browsers

Tags: html, css, background-image

What is the best practice to set a background image centered and 100% (so that it **fills the screen**, but still **retains the aspect ratio**) in all browsers?

Comment: What's "all browsers"? Does it include IE6? (For your own good, it better not.)

Comment: No, but all browsers up to date :) So, IE8, Firefox 3, Safari 4 and so on... and by all I mean all major browsers not Camino, Miro and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Picking up an old post, since there is a new method to do it with good browser support.

Use `background-image` like this:

```
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
```

This will not destroy the proportions of the image but scale it as best as possible never showing any black bars (or what ever would be in the background).

---

Browser support is almost perfect as you can see on [Can I use it?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts). Opera Mini could be an issue, but the browser will probably be replaced by Vivaldi soon.

In conclusion I think that this is definetly the way to go, since it´s by far the cleanest and most reliable solution and very easy to edit with JS aswell.

Comment: Thank you for updating an old thread. This is the way I do it today as well.

Answer (score 9):

Best solution I have managed to make so far is as follows;

```
//CSS
<style type="text/css">
   body {
       margin:0; padding:0;
   }
   html, body, #bg {
       height:100%;
       width:100%;
   }
   #bg {
       position:absolute; 
       left:0;
       right:0;
       bottom:0;
       top:0;
       overflow:hidden;
       z-index:0;
   }
   #bg img {
       width:100%;
       min-width:100%;
       min-height:100%;
   }
   #content {
       z-index:1;
   }
</style>

//HTML
<body>
<div id="bg">
   <img style="display:block;" src="bgimage.jpg">
</div>
<div id="content">
   //Rest of content
</div>
</body>
```

Might this be best way? Anyone see any problems with doing it this way?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 8):

The best practice is to **not** to do what you want to do.

By specifying 100% you are going to stretch (thus distort) the image.

The best way to have a simple, centered background is like this:

```
body {
    background-image:url(Images/MyBG.png);
    background-position:center top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat
}
```

**EDIT:**

Now you CAN target different resolutions and use a different background image, depending on the size by specifying a resolution-dependent stylesheet. You can use separate stylesheets just to define the one background element with different files in each.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" href="800.css" />
```

See: http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

or the [W3C CSS media query spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Comment: Problem with this solution is that I need to make many, many images with different resolution.

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent post on two methods to achieve this look:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: I did a modified version of Technique #2, works kind of okey, check my own answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to achieve this by setting it as a background image. However you could have a image that is absolutely positioned

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:0;right:0;bottom:0;top:0;display:table;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center">
<img style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%" />
</div>
```

Comment: What's the `display: table;` for?

Comment: for the vertical-align to work. it can also be display:table-cell

Comment: I don't think you need it for vertical-align to work, vertical-align is supposed to work on any inline-element: http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/vertical-align/

Comment: I am pretty sure IE will fail :)

Comment: also... when ur display is inline, ur height and weight style attributes will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CSS3 `background-size` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size), but i am not sure how well it is supported. I think most of them do but with prefix:

```
-o-background-size
-webkit-background-size 
-khtml-background-size
```